# Activity, Service and AsyncTask interfacing

Tags: android

I have one subclass of android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity(MyActivity), one subclass of android.app.Service and one subclass(MyAsyncTask) of android.os.AsyncTask.

Sample Code:
MyActivity.java

```
onCreate(...) { // start MyService }
```

MyService.java

```
onStartCommand(...){ // execute MyAsyncTask }
```

MyAsyncTask.java

```
onPostExecute(String result) { // send result to MyActivity};
```

My question is, how can i send results from `MyAsyncTask` when success to `MyActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

A way is to Bind your Activity to your service so that they can share a common communication channel.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to answer in a short paragraph. But basically what you want to do is use **binding** for your service.

It's certainly not a trivial task, but it's the elegant way to go. Besides of initiating your service with `startService()` you would additionally **bind** to your service. The binding mechanism allows your Activity to have a pointer to your Service class. With this pointer you can do whatever you want, including passing a pointer of the Activity itself to the Service, so the service would have a pointer to your Activity.

Once the Service has a pointer to your Activity, you can call any methods and set any variables you want, including setting the return value from your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a SingleInstance model with the MyActivity.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
  private static MyActivity instance;
  public static MyActivity getInstance(){
      return instance;
  }
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      instance = this;
      //xxx

  }

  public void onDestroy() {
       instance = null;
     ///
  }

  public void doSomething(){}
}
```

Then you can call MyActivity.getInstance().doSomething();inside the  onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

- use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), which is basically a `Service` that handles asynchronous requests
- send a broadcast from your `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` and receive it in you `Activity` (simple example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm))

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this structure and its works on my app. Hope its helpful. 
Create the service class extended with async task and singleton ..

```
 <service android:name=".myService" />
```

Service class

```
public class myService extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> 
{
    private Activity active  = null;
    protected myService () {}

     public static myService getInstance(Activity activity) {
      myService  myTask = new myService ();
      myTask.active = activity;
      return myTask;
     }

   public startTask()  {
     //start the async task.. 
     this.execute(new String[] {});
   }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 

    //check result sucess cond and call
    active.updateActivity(result)

    }
  }
```

Activity class

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         myService.getInstance(this).startTask();
    }

  public void updateActivity(result){
     //do something on activity with result...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can send result from service(MyAsyncTask.java  and MyService.java) class to activity(myactivity) class through "Broadcast"**

here is an example

in your onPostExecute(String result) method add those:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your  activity class[myactivity.java]");
intent.putExtra("RESULT", result)
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and your myactivity class
receive sending broadcast like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String bundle = intent.getStrings();// get resulting string and do whatever you want.
    }  

}
```

don't forget to register and unregister broadcast in myactivity class, like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("your service class"));
}     

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```